# What is a dragon king?

Tags: outliers, ranking, logrank-test, zipf

I am studying a system of cities where the largest city appears to be in many aspects an *outlier*. The distribution of city size - in any country -  are often claimed to follow Zipf's law.

According to Wikipedia Zipf's law is most easily observed by plotting the data on a log-log graph, with the axes being log (rank order) and log (frequency). The data conform to Zipf's law to the extent that the plot is linear.

However, I recently stumbled upon a paper where it is stated that an alternative view is that the "largest observation" are *Dragon Kings*.

Offcourse there is also a wiki article on the topic *Dragon Kings* to be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_king_theory). However I'm not sure I follow what is at stake in perceiving some observation as a *Black Swans* rather than a *Dragon King* and how this relates to Zipf's law.

Can anyone make this more plain or define in intuitive terms what a Dragon King is?

Comment: My (non-expert) reading is that to view an extreme event as a 'black swan' is to concede that it "lies outside the realm of regular expectations, because nothing in the past can convincingly point to its possibility", whereas viewing it as a 'dragon king' suggests an emphasis on the fact that extreme events can be predicted to some degree, if one has "a sufficiently deep understanding of the structure and dynamics of the focal system, and the ability to monitor it".

Comment: So viewing, say, very large earthquakes / pandemics / solar storms as black swans presumably would involve conceding that the events cannot be predicted and focusing on preparing for the eventual "big one", whereas someone who views them as "dragon kings" would be more apt to make a stab at predicting how and when very large ones would occur based on knowledge of the systems that cause them. At least that's my reading.

Comment: I believe you are on the right track - it is clarifying for me to say that the "black swan" is about the phenomena being "outside the realm of regular expectations" and that "dragon kings" are somehow predictable perhaps based on "knowledge of the systems that cause them." Still I do not get how this is related to the discussion of Zip's law for say for example city sizes.

Comment: If the other defining characteristic of dragon kings (besides their size) is being "born of unique origins (a "dragon") relative to its peers (other events from the same system)", then maybe the idea is that whatever normal systemic process causes most city sizes to follow Zipf's does not apply for the very largest cities: they achieved their size by some other (knowable, theoretically predictable, but different) process. Just a guess.